# Browser sniffing - Border Radius %

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, browser-detection, css

I thought it would be an idea to try to detect browsers that didn't support border-radius with % values. I've used the code below to try to detect for border radius but it's not playing ball. I get a empty alert box.

```
function getStyle(ele,styleProp){
            var x = document.getElementById(ele);
            if(x.currentStyle){
                var y = x.currentStyle[styleProp];
            }else if(window.getComputedStyle){
                var y = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(x,null).getPropertyValue(styleProp);
            }
            return y;               
        }

        $('body').append('<div id="test"></div>');

        var style = getStyle('test','-webkit-border-radius');
        alert(style);
```

I got this code from [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/getstyles.html)

It seems somewhat limited, it's fine for background-color, height & width, but will return empty for padding, margin and of course border-radius.

Any idea what's the cause of this limitation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Things like "margin", "padding", and "border-radius" are all shortcuts to the actual properties such as "margin-left", "padding-bottom", and "border-top-right-radius".  Try getting those.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) to detect border radius support or just have a look on their code.

Comment: Yes, and it's very good. However, unless I'm mistaken, you can't use it to detect specifically for browser that don't support % values.